# Get cell name from row and column index in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: vba, libreoffice-calc

I have a code that, when I press a button, takes values one by one from a sheet column called `REPARTITION PIECES`, creates a new tab called `FICHE INVENTAIRE` and sends them by value to that tab.

I would like to send the cell reference so that it then automatically changes in the `FICHE INVENTAIRE` when the `REPARTITION PIECES` changes.

For example, when I change cell A2 in `REPARTITION PIECES` I would have = `REPARTITION PIECES`$A$2 in the corresponding cell in `FICHE INVENTAIRE`.

This is the previous version:

```
          For n = 1 To ligs + 1
              y = Mid(celu(n), 6)
              y = y - 1
              nombre = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(col, y).String
              If nombre <> "" Then
                 li = li + 1
                 code = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(1, y).String
                 clair = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(2, y).String

thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D, li-l).String = Date()
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+1, li-l).String = code
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+2, li-l).String = clair
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+5, li-l).String = nombre
                 ' If li > 22 And D = 0 Then
                 '     D = 6
                 '     l = 22
                 ' End If
                 If strcomp(onglet, "FICHE INVENTAIRE") = 0 Then
                      borne = 30
                  Else
                      borne = 19
                  End If

                 If (li - l) >= borne Then
                      If strcomp(onglet, "FICHE INVENTAIRE") = 0 Then
                          li = 9
                      Else
                          li = 3
                      End If
                      If D = 0 Then
                          D = D + 6
                      Else
                          onglet = "VERSO FICHE INVENTAIRE"
                          li = 3
                          D = 0
                      End If
                  End If

              End If
         Next n
```

Comment: In other words, you want to split the table from the sheet "REPARTITION PIECES" into two sheets "FICHE INVENTAIRE" and "VERSO FICHE INVENTAIRE" by changing the order of the columns from nombre-code-clair to date-code-clair-nombre and at the same time replacing the values with formulas like `='REPARTITION PIECES'.$A$2`? In such a case, you should use something like `...getCellByPosition(D+1, li-l).setFormula("="&...getCellByPosition(1, y).AbsoluteName)` instead of `.String`

Comment: Thanks for you comment @JohnSUN ! That's almost that. I want some cells of  `REPARTITION PIECES` to give their values dynamically in the newly created tab `FICHE INVENTAIRE`

Comment: OK, why macro? Select data, copy it, jump to `FICHE INVENTAIRE` and Ctrl+Shift+V (Paste Special) - [As Link](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/02070000.html?System=WIN&DbPAR=CALC&HID=modules/scalc/ui/pastespecial/dialog-action_area1#bm_id31541011) - do it once and it will always work. Why macro?

Comment: Problem is that my `button(room)` creates an inventory record (FICHE INVENTAIRE) different for each room @JohnSUN

Comment: Well, the first recommendation still stands: get the source cell, read its `.AbsoluteName` property, set the formula to the target cell with `.setFormula("=" & ...)`